# Unable to retrieve and compare data from firebase in android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get Data and comparing it to the input data but it doesn't do anything. Pls Help me!`btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Routes").child("route1").child("Students").child("driver");

```
            databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() { 
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String phoneNumber = et_phone.getText().toString();
                    String password = et_password.getText().toString();
                    
                    String phone = dataSnapshot.child("Phone_No").getValue().toString();
                    String pass = dataSnapshot.child("Password").getValue().toString();
                   
                    if(phone.equals(phoneNumber)){
                        if(pass.equals(password)){
                           
                            startActivity(new Intent(Authentication.this, Home.class));

                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(Authentication.this, "Worng Password!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(Authentication.this, "Invalid PhoneNumber![enter image description here][1]", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }*/
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });`
```

Comment: what do you mean "doesn't do anything"? do you get the data correctly from firebase? explain your problem

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors? Besides that, please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Thanks. Now it is working as i missed one child from the Json tree